# How to write handlebars template in a javascript file

Tags: javascript, coding-style, pug, handlebars.js

A javascript handlebar template is usually added to the HTML file, it would be easier if we could keep all the templates in the javascript file, any best practices of doing that?

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
</script>
```

**Edit:** I can write this template using plain Javascript string as well, what are the other options?

```
var template = '<h1>{{title}}</h1>';
```

Comment: I think u should use handlebars'  precompiler. Pls check this out. http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that.

Cause the javascript to be executed by the browser is `type="text/javascript"` and handlebars template shouldn't be there.

======Edit=======

To make your code more clear, you can put handlebars template in another file.

Here is a example:

`test.php`

```
<?php

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0/handlebars.min.js" ></script>

<script>
    (function(){
        $('body').load('assets/template.js', function(){
            var template = Handlebars.compile( $('#template').html() );
            var data = {
                'name': 'jone doe',
                'email': 'xx@example.com'
            };

            $('body').append( template(data) ); 
        });


    })()
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`assets/template.js`

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="template">
    {{name}}
    {{email}}
</script>
```